# error handling in gulp 4

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to write simple watch task that will watch my tests files and on change compile them and run using [gulp-jasmine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jasmine).

My watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['tests/**/[^_]*.ts'], gulp.series(['compile_tests', 'test']));
})
```

and the test task:

```
gulp.task('test', function(){
    return gulp.src('tests/**/[^_]*.spec.js')
        .pipe(
            jasmine().on('error', function(error){
                console.log(error);
                this.emit('end');
            })
        );
});
```

But if tested code contain errors, like `is not a function` or whatever, watch task crashes and I have to restart it again and again. My error handler not even being called. So how can I handle errors in proper way?

Answer (score 2):

> Try this way to handle error

```
 gulp.task('test', function(){
        var j = jasmine({});
        j.on('error',function(e){
            console.log(e);
            j.end();
      });
      return gulp.src('tests/**/[^_]*.spec.js')
          .pipe(j);
    });
```